# Как в Maven проекте добавить mysql-connector

Tags: maven, mysqlconnector

Как в Maven проекте добавить mysql-connector?

Answer (score 3):

Все разобрался: File >>> Project Structure >>> Libraries кликаем плюсик и добавляем скачаный jar файл конектор